# CSS to edit overflow scrollbar for Joomla custom module

Tags: module, scrollbar, overflow, joomla3.3

I have a [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) 3.3 custom module, and I've added the overflow attribute which works fine. How can I change the scroll bar color, width and rounded corners ***for this module alone*** without affecting the page scroll bar for the entire page?

Comment: How did you add the overflow attribute? Why cant you do it the same way?

Comment: Does the module have an ID or class?

Comment: @tomjm, add WHAT? That's the question